# The best USB for a portable system

Tags: usb, linux, portable

Does anyone know a USB disk that's considerably fast and capacitive but it doesn't get very hot?

Currently I own a SanDisk Ultraflair 3.0 and even without moving anything it gets hot. For example, when I was moving an approximately 10 GB file, I couldn't even touch it for a minute, so I obviously can't run any OS. My OTG 2.0 USB is too slow.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: IMHO you could improve your question a little, at least write ”USB disk“ rather than just ”USB“ in the title. The term ”USB“ itself refers to protocols and specifications, not to a device. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

Answer (score 1):

How about get a USB 3 to SATA adapter, and attach a 2.5" SSD to it.

or this

[https://www.amazon.com/M-2-External-Converter-Adapter-Enclosure/dp/B076DCNZM3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076DCNZM3)

or this nvme version:

[https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-EC-NVME-Aluminum-Enclosure-Nvme/dp/B07K4TZQ7D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K4TZQ7D)

Comment: … and then (maybe) look for a HDD which doesn't get too hot.